# Using conditional statements to change colour of values in table (kableextra)

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table using kableextra. I want to change the colours of the values, so that those values >= 85 are changed to green, and those < 50 are coloured red, using the cell_spec function via a loop that iterates over the data frame, and conditional statements that specify the values that need to change.

I've been able to change a single value using the kableextra documentation and specifying every column I want changed, but I want to use multiple if statements instead of ifelse, unless there is a better way.

The code I have been using so far is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

Subject <- c("Database", "Java", "C++", "Physics", "Mathematics", "English", "Chemistry", "Networks", "Security")
A <- c(69, 64, 70, 57, 80, 34, 45, 56, 96)
B <- c(70, 74, 68, 76, 71, 56, 56, 45, 30)
C <- c(84, 58, 87, 78, 67, 67, 43, 34, 56)
D <- c(78, 83, 68, 72, 90, 48, 23, 23, 46)
E <- c(79, 55, 91, 71, 34, 26, 76, 67, 75)
F <- c(80, 72, 64, 45, 66, 76, 45, 56, 54)
G <- c(90, 67, 76, 51, 45, 59, 33, 64, 34)
H <- c(60, 59, 88, 90, 76, 34, 43, 72, 45)


student_results <- data.frame(Subject, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)

rownames(student_results) <- c("Database", "Java", "C++", "Physics", "Mathematics", "English", "Chemistry", "Networks", "Security")

student_results %>%
    mutate(
      A = cell_spec(A, "html", color = ifelse(A >= 85, "coral", "black")),
      B = cell_spec(B, "html", color = ifelse(B >= 85, "coral", "black")),
      C = cell_spec(C, "html", color = ifelse(C >= 85, "coral", "black")),
      D = cell_spec(D, "html", color = ifelse(D >= 85, "coral", "black")),
      E = cell_spec(E, "html", color = ifelse(E >= 85, "coral", "black")),
      F = cell_spec(F, "html", color = ifelse(F >= 85, "coral", "black")),
      G = cell_spec(G, "html", color = ifelse(G >= 85, "coral", "black")),
      H = cell_spec(H, "html", color = ifelse(H >= 85, "coral", "black"))
    ) %>%
    kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling("striped", full_width = FALSE)
```

This successfully changes one range of values, but I want to be able to format multiple ranges, and avoid needing to specify each column individually when dealing with large data sets.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change multiple columns at once, you can use `mutate_at`. To have multiple conditions, you can use nested `ifelse` conditions. Nested `ifelse`'s get unwieldy after a while so you could instead look into `case_when`.

```
student_results %>%
    mutate_at(vars(A:H), ~ cell_spec(
        ., "html", 
        color = ifelse(. >= 85, "coral", ifelse(. < 50, "red", "black"))
    )) %>%
    kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling("striped", full_width = FALSE)
```